# A thread that can be interrupted before starting

Tags: java, multithreading

As per the [Java documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--):

> Interrupting a thread that is not alive need not have any effect.

Particularly, interrupting a thread between the call to [start()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#start--) and the invocation of [run()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#run--) has no effect.

So I wrote a `Thread` which can be interrupted even before it started, so that the interrupted state is communicated once it started:

```
/**
 * A thread that can be interrupted before actually starting (that is between the moment {@link
 * #start} is called and {@link #run} is invoked.
 */
public final class InterruptableThread extends Thread {
    private final AtomicBoolean mInterrupted = new AtomicBoolean(false);
    private final Object mLock = new Object();
    private final AtomicBoolean mStarted = new AtomicBoolean(false);

    public InterruptableThread(Runnable runnable) {
        super(runnable);
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mStarted.set(true);
            if (mInterrupted.get()) {
                super.interrupt();
            }
        }

        super.run(); // Let the original runnable handle the interruption by itself.
    }

    @Override
    public void interrupt() {
        synchronized (mLock) {
            mInterrupted.set(true);
            if (mStarted.get()) {
                super.interrupt();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

It seems safe to me, although the `AtomicBoolean` are maybe not required. But because we're dealing with multithreading here, another point of view is welcome.

I need this in a library with `start()` and `stop()` methods which look like:

```
public void start() {
    synchronized (mStartStopLock) {
        myThread = new InterruptableThread(myRunnable);
        myThread.start();
    }
}

public void stop() {
    synchronized (mStartStopLock) {
        myThread.interrupt();
        myThread.join();
    }
}
```

As you can see, despite the lock, if `start()` and `stop()` are called immediately one after another, nothing guarantees that `interrupt()` will have effect on the thread if it's a regular Java `Thread`. That's important because the `Runnable` uses the interrupted status for stopping itself.

Comment: Could you include a use case to show this API in action?

Comment: I posted this as a comment below but I think it might be worth mentioning here: Alternately, use an `ExecutorService` and get a `Future` when submitting jobs.  You can `.cancel` a `Future` before it starts.

Comment: @markspace I think this comment should be promoted to an answer instead, since OP does not want to reinvent the wheel.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Review

- A [Java Thread](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted--)'s default behavior is:

  > A thread interruption ignored because a thread was not alive at the
  >   time of the interrupt will be reflected by this method returning
  >   false.
- Changing the default behavior of interruption in a thread's lifecycle seems a bit tricky to me. I don't think you should override exising methods to change their specification when dealing with such common and wellknown threading constructs.
- Instead, I would create 2 new methods, `requestRun()` and `requestInterruption()` to clearly indicate different functionality from `run()` and `interrupt()`.
- If you do decide to override `run()` and `interrupt()` make sure to clearly state in the Javadoc that the specification of these methods has changed.
- `InterruptableThread` is an unfortunate name, since `Thread` is also interruptible. A better name would be `PreemptiveInterruptibleThread`.
- Since you have atomic booleans, perhaps you could check the value before taking the lock, in order to mitigate access to the locks. There is a possible race condition though. You can read more about [Double-checked locking](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Double-checked_locking) here. Is your question implementation *Idempotent*?
- If the atomic booleans are only used inside this lock, they could be replaced with ordinary booleans.
- I like the fact everything that could be made final, has been declared final.
- I do believe there still is a race condition after releasing the lock in `run()` and before calling `super.run()`.

Comment: Alternately, use an `ExecutorService` and get a `Future` when submitting jobs.  You can `.cancel` a `Future` before it starts.

Comment: Only `requestInterruption()` is required, overriding `requestRun()` the way I did does not change the thread's specification. Moreover starting/stopping the library is not critical performance-wise, so the atomic booleans can be replaced and the lock kept for simplicity. Finally there is no race condition because the thread is alive as soon as the inherited `run()` is invoked, hence the thread is marked as interrupted in any case, which is what we want. I agree with all the rest, thanks for your answer.